# Comparing two successive rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have Database table payment such as below

```
 level_count | amount 
__________________________
     650     | 12
     1000    | 35
     1700    | 50
__________________________
```

Now Wanted to check if I supplied input as 650 which is level_count column value. Then I should get amount as 12. Then If I supplied input as 999 I should still get 12. Means It should compare its successive rows and compare. Suppose If I enter 1200 then I should get 35 and If I enter 1700 or above I should get 50.
I have tried flowing but didn't got any success.

Where I am going wrong.

```
SELECT * FROM payment  T1 
INNER JOIN payment  T2 on T1.level_count>=T2.level_count AND T1.level_count<T2.level_count 
WHERE T1.level_count = '650'
```

When I execute above query I get no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using a `LIMIT` query here:

```
SELECT *
FROM payment
WHERE level_count <= 999     -- or 650, or another input value
ORDER BY level_count DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The logic of the above query works in two parts.  First, the `WHERE` clause removes all records for which the `level_count` is *greater* than the input value.  But this still leaves us potentially with more than one record (which include the record we actually want).  The `LIMIT` trick then keeps the single remaining record with the *highest* `level_count`.

Comment: Include = operator in your comparison, otherwise for exact levels it will returns lower level amount.